# Android values not inserting in my mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to insert some values from editTexts into my local database but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int REQUEST_INTERNET = 100;
    EditText et_name, et_password;
    Button send;
    String name,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.INTERNET},REQUEST_INTERNET);
            return;
        }

        et_name = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        et_password = findViewById(R.id.et_pass);
        send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    }
    public void reguser(View view){


if (name != null){
    name= et_name.getText().toString();
}
if (password != null){
    password= et_password.getText().toString();

}
        String method= "register";

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask= new BackgroundTask(this);

        backgroundTask.execute(method,name,password);


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_INTERNET){
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the http request:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://127.0.0.1/stHans/parkinsonism.php";
        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("register")){
            String name = params[1];
            String password =params[2];

            try {
                URL url =new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                is.close();
                return "Registered!";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php
 require "init.php";

if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

 $u_name=$_POST["name"];
 $u_password=$_POST["password"];

 $sql_query="INSERT INTO parkinsonism_value(name,password) VALUES('".$u_name."','".$u_password."');";
}


?>
```

Is it because of the permission?
because the connection to the database is already checked and its fully operating. I've tried and changed everything and every part of the code but still it seems it won't work for no reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? The query you are building (which is widely open to SQL injection!) is not executed

Comment: @NicoHaase: Sorry I'm totaly strange in working with server-side... how should I execute this though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just needed this line of code in the beginning:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The proper solution which prevents SQL Injection and does the job is the following:**

This is how your **init.php** should look like(you need to replace the authentication details with yours):

```
$servername = "localhost"; // localhost by default
$username = "db_username"; // root by default
$password = "db_password";// empty by default
$dbname = "db_name"; // your db name
$conn="";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);// this allows to show you errors
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

and this is how your php code should look like:

```
<?php

require "init.php";

if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

 $u_name=$_POST["name"];
 $u_password=$_POST["password"];


// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO parkinsonism_value(name, password) VALUES (?, ?)");

// here it prepares a your sql query, leave it exactly as it is, the question marks are part of the code, they represent placeholders for information.

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $u_name, $u_password);
// here it binds your variables to the question marks above, therefore $u_name will bind to the first question mark, and $u_password to the second question mark.
// "ss" in bind param stands for the type of data you have if your username and password are strings it will be "ss" (if let's say your username was an int then instead of "ss" you would have "is" which resulted in $stmt->bind_param("is", $u_name, $u_password) );

$stmt->execute();// here it executes the query above with the parameters after this code has been executed you should have your information inserted in your database.

}
```

***Bonus tip:*** use var_dump($_POST) to see if your variables are actually set and it will display not only the information received from your android application but also the type of data.

If you need further help feel free to reply to my answer.

Comment: thanks man, I appreciate your sincere help, but the problem is the values still are not sending to database. the table is still empty...

Comment: To troubleshoot just do the following: above the line with the  if ( isset(...) )
write var_dump($_POST); if nothing shows up it is something wrong from the Android side. If you will get some text printed by var_dump then for the name John it will show something like string(4)  "John"; If var_dump prints you the name and password details but nothing shows up in the database it may be a misconfiguration in your init.php or mysql.

Comment: :It gives me array(0){ }

Comment: First of all check if your path is correct http://127.0.0.1/stHans/parkinsonism.php

this means that you have a folder in your htdocs or public_html named stHanks with this exact spelling and capitalization, inside of which is the parkinsonism.php file. In this php file you should have the php code mentiond in my comment.

Other thing to check is to disable mobile data on your android device, and enable wi-fi only, and be sure that your android device and localhost are connected to the same router.

Comment: Regarding inseration to your MySQL: Just as a test you can do the following: get rid of the if( isset(...) ) statement and hardcode this $_POST["name"] = "name_test", $_POST["password]="password_test" this will show up in your parkinsonism_value table as a row containing "name_test" in your name colum and "password_test" in your password column.